# Export a mysql table into CSV using PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a my sql table called pvdata, I would like to export it to csv file.

But I'm obtaining the following results instead of the normal looking table:

```
 <br />
 <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1'cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
 <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: header in C:\wamp\www\EXPORT TABLE\index.php on line <i>28</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0035</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>256088</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\EXPORT TABLE\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
"id id  state   id  state   Longitude   id  state   Longitude   Latitude    id  state   Longitude   Latitude    Altitude(km)    id  state   Longitude   Latitude    Altitude(km)    Module Tilt id  state   Longitude   Latitude    Altitude(km)    Module Tilt Module Azimuth  id  state   Longitude   Latitude    Altitude(km)    Module Tilt Module Azimuth  Rated Peak Power(kW)    id  state   Longitude   Latitude    Altitude(km)    Module Tilt Module Azimuth  Rated Peak Power(kW)    Temperature losses coefficient  id  state   Longitude   Latitude    Altitude(km)    Module Tilt Module Azimuth  Rated Peak Power(kW)    Temperature losses coefficient  Nominal Operation Cell Temperature  id  state   Longitude   Latitude    Altitude(km)    Module Tilt Module Azimuth  Rated Peak Power(kW)    Temperature losses coefficient  Nominal Operation Cell Temperature  Invertor Effeciency id  state   Longitude   Latitude    Altitude(km)    Module Tilt Module Azimuth  Rated Peak Power(kW)    Temperature losses coefficient  Nominal Operation Cell Temperature  Invertor Effeciency Persil Name <br />"
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\wamp\www\EXPORT TABLE\index.php on line <i>49</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0035</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>256088</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\EXPORT TABLE\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>"id  state   Longitude   Latitude    Altitude(km)    Module Tilt Module Azimuth  Rated Peak Power(kW)    Temperature losses coefficient  Nominal Operation Cell Temperature  Invertor Effeciency Persil Name "
"1  ""persil""  ""0""   ""0""   ""0""   ""0""   ""0""   ""0""   ""0.0047""  ""47""  ""0.9"" ""PERSIL07"""
"2  ""other""   ""12""  ""12""  ""0""   ""15""  ""150"" ""12""  ""0.0046""  ""45""  ""0.95""    ""predefined"""
```

My php code is:

```
  <?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("user data smart grid",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select Data Base");

    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pvdata.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");



$query = "SELECT * FROM pvdata";

$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";

    echo $header;
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

print "$header\n$data";

exit();

?>
```

so what's going wrong? 
If I export the table manually from the phpmyadmin, it works fine.
I also want to get the names of the columns in the table if possible.

Comment: Because your quote signs in header and data are placed improperly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before for loop initialize $header to empty string.

```
$header = '';//initialize header
for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";

    echo $header;//remove this line
}
```

**EDIT**

Also initialize $data outside while loop.

```
$data = '';
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Isn't $header empty at start? Vars in PHP does not have to be initialised before use...

Comment: Also you need to initialize $data outside while loop.

Comment: @PAM Variable need to initialize because it is used with .= concatination operator.

Comment: @HarishAnchu Yes it's better now, but the cells are still not separated, and some column names are repeated more than once in an arbitrary order

Comment: Remove the echo line inside for loop.

Comment: Cells are not separated because you didn't specify any delimiter in between data.

Comment: @HarishAnchu ok just one more things the name of the rows are all on the same line (not separated)

Comment: @HarishAnchu Yes I noticed, how can I specify the delimiter it should be instead of " or  ""

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32561/discussion-between-harish-anchu-and-maggie)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a typo, but within your script are spaces before the

```
   <?php
```

this will result in an html document being delivered and your header-calls will fail. So remove the spaces and any other output before "header" calls.

You are getting error messages up there, for a quick solution try:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Line 28: $header is not known, this makes

```
$header .=
```

appending to a unknown variable.

Comment: There's no space before <?php

Answer (score 0):

You can use fputcsv function for clear code.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code -**

```
<?php

    // Database Connection

    $host="localhost";
    $uname="root";
    $pass="";
    $database = "a2zwebhelp"; 

    $connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 

    echo mysql_error();

    //or die("Database Connection Failed");
    $selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or 
    die("Database could not be selected"); 
    $result=mysql_select_db($database)
    or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

    // Fetch Record from Database

    $output = "";
    $table = ""; // Enter Your Table Name 
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from $table");
    $columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

    // Get The Field Name

    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
    $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
    }
    $output .="\n";

    // Get Records from the table

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
    }
    $output .="\n";
    }

    // Download the file

    $filename = time().'csv'; //For unique file name
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

    echo $output;
    exit;

    ?>
```

Courtesy - [Export MySQL table to CSV using PHP](http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/export-data-to-csv)