# Export data into csv file in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have made page in php which shows some users data like name , email , address etc in different columns.The data come from the data base. Now i want to export all the information in .csv file is there any solution for it in php.
below is the code which display data on page.

```
<table  width='98%' align="center" id='Categories_Main' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'  class="table table-striped">            
            <tr height="25">
              <th class="cat_list" colspan="4"><br /><?php echo $this->db->get_modules($cid);?><br /><br /></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th width="150" style="min-width:55px" class="nowrap center"><a   class="hasTip">Gender </a></th>
              <th width="150" style="min-width:55px" class="nowrap center"><a   class="hasTip">Name</a></th>
              <th width="150" style="min-width:55px" class="nowrap center"><a   class="hasTip">Adress</a></th>
              <th width="150" style="min-width:55px" class="nowrap center"><a   class="hasTip">Email</a></th>
              <th width="150" style="min-width:55px" class="nowrap center"><a   class="hasTip">Number</a></th>
              <th width="150" style="min-width:55px" class="nowrap center"><a   class="hasTip">Course</a></th>
              <th width="150" style="min-width:55px" class="nowrap center"><a   class="hasTip">Price</a></th>
              <th width="150" style="min-width:55px" class="nowrap center"><a   class="hasTip">Action</a></th>
           </tr>
              <?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM 
                            prospective_request  

                            ORDER BY name ASC limit $st,$limit";        

                $this->db->query($sql);
                while($this->db->fetch_array())
                {
              ?>


                  <th class="nowrap has-context" width="200" style="min-width:55px">
                        <div class="pull-left"> <p style='margin-left: 10px; text-align:center'><?php echo showLink($this->db->record['user_title'],"?module=prospective_request&func=view&page=$page&cid=".$this->db->record['id'], $this->db->record['id']);?>
                        </p></div></th>
                        <th class="nowrap has-context" width="200" style="min-width:55px">
                        <div class="pull-left"> <p style='margin-left: 10px; text-align:center'><?php echo showLink($this->db->record['name'],"?module=prospective_request&func=view&page=$page&cid=".$this->db->record['id'], $this->db->record['id']);?>
                        </p></div></th>
                        <th class="nowrap has-context" width="200" style="min-width:55px">
                        <div class="pull-left"> <p style='margin-left: 10px; text-align:center'><?php echo showLink($this->db->record['address'],"?module=prospective_request&func=view&page=$page&cid=".$this->db->record['id'], $this->db->record['id']);?>
                        </p></div></th>
                        <th class="nowrap has-context" width="200" style="min-width:55px">
                        <div class="pull-left"> <p style='margin-left: 10px; text-align:center'><?php echo showLink($this->db->record['email'],"?module=prospective_request&func=view&page=$page&cid=".$this->db->record['id'], $this->db->record['id']);?>
                        </p></div></th>
                        <th class="nowrap has-context" width="200" style="min-width:55px">
                        <div class="pull-left"> <p style='margin-left: 10px; text-align:center'><?php echo showLink($this->db->record['number'],"?module=prospective_request&func=view&page=$page&cid=".$this->db->record['id'], $this->db->record['id']);?>
                        </p></div></th>
                        <th class="nowrap has-context" width="200" style="min-width:55px">
                        <div class="pull-left"> <p style='margin-left: 10px; text-align:center'><?php echo showLink($this->db->record['course'],"?module=prospective_request&func=view&page=$page&cid=".$this->db->record['id'], $this->db->record['id']);?>
                        </p></div></th>
                        <th class="nowrap has-context" width="200" style="min-width:55px">
                        <div class="pull-left"> <p style='margin-left: 10px; text-align:center'><?php echo showLink($this->db->record['total_price'],"?module=prospective_request&func=view&page=$page&cid=".$this->db->record['id'], $this->db->record['id']);?>
                        </p></div></th>


                    <th class="tabletxt" width="200" style="min-width:55px"><p align='left'>
                        <?php 
                        if($cid){ 
                    ?>
                    <a href="javascript:changeStatus(<?php echo $this->db->record['id'];?>,<?php echo ($this->db->record['status']==1)?"0":"1";?>, <?php echo $this->db->record['parent_id'];?>,<?php echo $page; ?>);"><img src="images/<?php echo ($this->db->record['status']==1)?"active":"inactive";?>.gif" border="0" align="absbottom" alt="<?php echo ($this->db->record['status']==1)?"Active - Click to deactivate":"Inactive - Click to activate";?>" /></a>&nbsp;

                    <?php } //IF ?>

                   <a href="index.php?module=prospective_request&func=edit&page=<?php echo $page;?>&cid=<?php echo $this->db->record['id'];?>&pid=<?php echo $cid;?>"><img src="images/editrec.png" border="0" align="absbottom" alt="Edit Record" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:delete_module('<?php echo $this->db->record['id']; ?>', '<?php echo $page;?>')" title="Delect Record"><img src="images/delete.gif" border="0" align="absbottom" alt="Delete Record" /></a>
                   </p> </th>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                    } //While
                  ?>
                    <form name="frmChangeStatus" action="index.php?module=prospective_request&func=view&page=<?=$page?>&cid=<?=$_GET['cid'];?>" method="post" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="" />
                        <input name="cat_id" type="hidden" value="" />
                        <input name="prospective_request" type="hidden" value="" />
                    </form> 

        <tr>
           <td class="sub" align="center" colspan="6">
             <?php
                      pagination($numpages, $page, "?module=".$_GET['module']."&func=".$_GET['func']."&cid=".$cid );
                    ?>        
                  </td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362686/export-a-mysql-table-into-csv-using-php-code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/362491/how-to-export-the-data-as-csv-file-from-mysql-in-php

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tracend/3133975

Comment: http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2010/02/create-a-csv-with-php/

Comment: I think the landing page on SO should become a search box...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast solution, use a temporary variable for the rows of the data to be exported.
E.g., before your while cycle:

```
[...]
$this->db->query($sql);
$separator=";";    // Separator to be used in your file
$crlf="\r\n";      // End of line
// Array with the fields to be exported, indexeded on your db fields:
$a_exp=array("gender"="Gender"
            ,"name"=>"Name"
            ,"address"=>"Address"
            ,"email"=>"Email"
            ,"number"=>"Number"
            ,"course"=>"Course"
            ,"price"=>"Price"
            ,"action"=>"Action");
$csv=""; // Add additional headers here
//Header
while(list($field,$descr)=each($a_exp)) {
    $csv.=$descr.$separator;
}
$csv.=$crlf;
while($this->db->fetch_array()) {
    // And here you can add the rows
    reset($a_exp);
    while(list($field,$descr)=each($a_exp)) {
        $csv.=$this->db->record[$field].$separator;
    }
    $csv.=$crlf;
    [...]
}
// At the end of the while cycle you can save the file
$f=fopen("/path/to/your/file.csv","a");
fwrite($f,$csv);
fclose($csv);
```

Alternately, you can use the built-in fputcsv function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) or existing CSV export libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Store data in variable in the same way you are displaying in table

`$content="col1,col2,col3\n\r";`
`$content.="data1,data2,data3\n\r";`
`$content.="data4,data5,data6\n\r";`

the first line of above code are the headings of the columns in excel
the line `\n\r` in csv is same as `</tr><tr>`(new row) in html table

run this code to make csv file

`$filename = "yourfile.csv";`
`$f = fopen($filename, 'w');`
`fwrite($f, $content);`
`fclose($f);`

then run the below code to make the file download

`header("Cache-Control: public");`
`header("Content-Description: File Transfer");`
`header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");`
`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");`
`header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");`
`header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");`
`readfile($filename);`